# Laravel 8 Testing - using RefreshDatabase but table not found

Tags: laravel, testing, phpunit

I'm trying to refactor a class and having problems testing it when I place certain code in the `__constructor` method and it throws an error that `table not found` within the test but works outside of tests.

I know this means that in the testing environment the table has yet to be created and although I'm using `RefreshDatabase` within the test it appears that at the point the class I'm testing initialises and attempts to access the database it's not ready. So I'm either doing something in the constructor I shouldn't  or I'm missing something in my test structure.

Here's the basics of the class I'm tryting to test:

```
class PlayerRounds
{

    use EclecticPresenter;

    private RoundRepository $roundRepository;

    private CourseRepository $courseRepository;

    private $courseHoles;

    public function __construct(RoundRepository $roundRepository, CourseRepository $courseRepository)
    {
        $this->roundRepository = $roundRepository;
        $this->courseRepository = $courseRepository;
        $this->init();

    }

  private function init()
    {
        $this->courseHoles = $this->courseRepository->all();
    }

    /**
     * generates eclecic rounds for each league the player is in
     * @param Player $player
     */
    public function getAllEclecticRounds(Player $player)
    {
        $allEclecticRounds = collect();

        $leagues = $player->league()->where('league_type', 'eclectic')->get();

        $leagues->each(function ($league) use ($player, $allEclecticRounds) {
            $newRound = $this->getPlayerEclecticRound($player, $league);
            $allEclecticRounds->put($league->id, $newRound);
        });

        return $allEclecticRounds;
    }
```

The test fails at the `init()` method. The fetch `$this->courseHoles = $this->courseRepository->all();` the the test fails with a `table not found` error if it's within the constructor, It works if I place this piece of code within each method that needs it but means I call it often rather than once.

Here's my test:

```
class PlayerRoundsTest extends TestCase
{
    use RefreshDatabase;
    use EclecticTestHelper;
    use WithFaker;

    private $playerRounds;

    protected function setUp(): void
    {
        parent::setUp();

        $this->seed(CourseTableSeeder::class);

        $this->playerRounds = app()->make(PlayerRounds::class);
    }

    /**
     * @test
     * @covers PlayerRounds::getAllEclecticRounds
     * @description:
     */
    public function it_returns_an_eclectic_round_for_all_leagues()
    {
        $player = Player::factory()->has(League::factory()->count(3))->create();

        foreach ($player->league()->get() as $league) {
            for ($x = 0; $x <= 3; $x++) {
                $this->createScores($league, $player);
            }
        }

        $result = $this->playerRounds->getAllEclecticRounds($player);

        $this->assertCount(3, $result);
        $result->each(function($collection) {
            $this->assertCount(1, $collection);
        });
```

Are there any ideas how I can initiate the class correctly and get the test set up correct and ensure the database is ready for the test. I assumed using `RefreshDatabase` was the correct approach and I had things in the correct order.

Thank you

**update
If I change the `constructor` to this:

```
   public function __construct(RoundRepository $roundRepository, CourseRepository $courseRepository)
    {
        $this->roundRepository = $roundRepository;
        $this->courseRepository = $courseRepository;
    }
```

and then place the code that calls on the database to the method used in the test back to this:

```
public function getPlayerEclecticRound(Player $player, League $league, $maxDate = null)
    {
        // FIXME: Initiate at start in constructor but fails in tests
        $this->courseHoles = $this->courseRepository->all();

       //rest of code removed for brevity
    }
```

This then passes the test.

This class needs the data in `$this->courseHoles` for a number of methods to work so I'm aiming to just call this once at initialization rather than every time I access the method as it is now but can' get it to work in a testing environment.

note I'm using a mysql database on the server but a sqllite memory database in testing

###update
Ok, after a bit of playing around the error is being caused by the loading of a custom artisan command I created. That command class has a dependancy of another class which in turn calls on the class I'm tresting.

I removed the command from `Kernel.php` as follows:

```
protected $commands = [
        Inspire::class,
        FixtureReminder::class,
        SmsFixtureReminder::class,
        UpdateMigrationTable::class,
//        EclecticUpdate::class,
//        MatchplayUpdate::class,
        CleanTemporaryFiles::class,
        AuthPermissionCommand::class
    ];
```

So - am I right in assuming for test purposes this is going to be impossible to isolate without changing this each time? This all relates to dependencies and the order in which `CreateApplication` works but I don't know enough to work around this.

Comment: Everything looks fine, can you explain more when this works in your tests ?

Comment: Hi - yes - I'll update the question to show how I can get this to work...

Comment: Could you create a new database in your mysql and use that for testing just to see if sqlite is the problem ?

Comment: Thank you.  I'll give that a try shortly.  :)

Comment: Did it work ? Where you able to try it ?

Comment: In did try but the same results.  I didn't get long on it last night but not convinced my mysql set up on a server database was correct (for the testing environment)so going to try again this afternoon.

Comment: Ok - isolated it to a custom command in `kernel.php` that has a dependancy on that class. So looks as if there's a sequencing issue in the way the app is created during testing

Comment: Can you explain more what this command does ? It should not give you any issues

Comment: The command is a simple one that generates an email to users on a weekly basis. The email though requires a PDF attachment based on a league table. The command calls on a class to generate the PDF (`PDFGenerator`) which in turn uses another class to fetch the league table  (`EclecticLeague'). Currently reviewing my dependency injection to see if I can refactor and get this better

Comment: You can update the question with it